# multiple outstanding requests

Tags: network-programming

I don't really understand the expression "multiple outstanding requests".

could you please give me an example?

what is an outstanding request? what is the oposite of an "outstanding request"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An outstanding request is one which has not been served yet.

For instance, an application could make 30 concurrent requests to different web servers.  10 of them may come back with a response, while the other 20 have not been serviced.  Therefore, those 20 are outstanding since they are waiting for a response.

The opposite would be one that is served or completed I guess.

You can use an analogy of a restaurant.  If you ask a waiter for water and a spoon, and he only returns you a water, then your request for a spoon is outstanding.  It isn't complete until he gives you your spoon or tells you that he doesn't have one to give you.